# В каком случае не следует ставить запятую перед "что"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

У меня вот такая проблема: мой друг спорит со мной, что во фразе "**если что**" запятая ставится. Мало того, он утверждает, что перед "что" запятая ставится всегда, при любом раскладе.
***При каких условиях запятая перед "что" не ставится?***

Comment: Я все правила не помню, но ставлю запятые на слух. "Про себя" в мозгах проговариваю предложение; если есть короткая пауза перед словом, то ставлю запятую. На то и препинанием сие назвали. В вашем случае, барышня, запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Запятая перед "что" ставится не всегда. Заблуждение идет из начальной школы. Там прямо в рамочке есть такое правило. Но учитель должен уточнить: запятая перед "что" всегда обычно ставится в текстах, предназначенных для первого-второго классов, а в более трудных может и не ставиться. Но у многих именно это правило надолго остается в памяти. Поэтому даже в газетных текстах можно увидеть фразы типа "А, что случилось?" Здесь запятая не нужна. Вообще таких правил нет, когда бы условием постановки знака было бы конкретное слово. Постановка запятой зависит от структуры предложения. В разговорной фразе "если что" (например, *"я тебе позвоню, если что"*) запятая не нужна, так как придаточное усечено до одного слова "что" (если что случится).
Не нужна также запятая при однородных придаточных: *я знаю, что написать и что сказать.* После частиц: *И что ты хочешь мне сказать".* Слово "что" может быть местоимением, частицей, союзом, междометием - трудно так сразу обобщить все случаи. Еще раз повторю, что знаки зависят от структуры предложения, а не от конкретного слова.