# Нужна запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

**Есть все что пожелаете.** (Имеется).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) **Есть всё,  что пожелаете.**  (2) **Бери что хочешь** (что нравится, что душе угодно).

**Следует отличать сложноподчиненные предложения (СПП)  от цельных по смыслу выражений.**

СПП имеют стандартную структуру: "всё"  – опорное местоимение в главной части, "что"  – союзное слово в придаточной части.

Цельные выражения, имеющие форму придаточного, на самом деле эквивалентны члену предложения: бери **что хочешь**  – бери **любую вещь**.

И вывод: **не всегда "по правилам русского языка перед "что" нужно ставить запятую".** Соответственно, **принятый правильный ответ** (надо ставить запятую) имеет **некорректное объяснение**. Здесь дело не в тире, а в наличии или отсутствии запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Есть всё, что пожелаете. Тире здесь не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, придаточное предложение отделяется запятой от главного.

**Есть всё, что пожелаете.**

Пример из Нац. корпуса русского языка:

*К вашим услугам все, что пожелаете [Ксения Яхонтова. Смятение Анастасии (1996-1998)]*

Существует ошибочное мнение, что перед "что" всегда нужно ставить запятую. Этот вопрос уже обсуждался. См.:  [В каком случае следует ставить запятую перед "что"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/22801/%d0%92-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be)

Answer (score -1):

По правилам русского языка перед "что" нужно ставить запятую. Тире же сюда не вписывается вообще.
Пример:
Есть все, что пожелаете.

Comment: Нет такого правила. Примеры: Он что ни попало в дом тащит. Если что, сразу позвони.

Comment: Важный для понимания пример: И вот предоставленный самому себе, я должен был самостоятельно решать, как мне быть и что делать? [Г. А. Соломон (Исецкий). Среди красных вождей (1930)]

Comment: Я не опровергаю остальные случаи. Я лишь, как вы заметили, указал на один, заданный в вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо за примеры и Ваше внимание, но не думаю, что опубликовавшему вопрос человеку было бы интересно читать углубленную тему. Ответ очевиден. Отсюда возникает и отношение. И все же, мне приятно, что есть люди, которые относятся к нашему языку весьма серьезно. )

Comment: Я и другие участники поняли Ваш ответ так: есть, дескать, правила, утверждающие, что перед "что" нужно ставить запятую. А предложение  "Есть все, что пожелаете" Вы привели как пример, подтверждаюший эти "правила". С таким ответом не могу согласиться. А если Вы имели в виду что-то другое, то измените формулировку.

Comment: @ИнтеллигентныйМистерЕнот *Я лишь, как вы заметили, указал на один, заданный в вопросе.* - в таком случае ваш ответ содержит ошибочную формулировку, а потому нуждается в существенном редактировании или вообще подлежит удалению. Исправьте, пожалуйста.